# Getting build issue while building kotlin code. "Unresolved reference: datetime in kotlin "

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

The Complete error is
Execution failed for task ':compileKotlinJs'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details
> Unresolved reference: datetime

this issue is coming when I do "import kotlinx.datetime.Clock" and i have implemented implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.1.1").

Can someone help ?

Comment: Please, file an issue and attach your project - https://kotl.in/issue.

Comment: It might help to include the build.gradle file (or build.gradle.kts) for your multiplatform project. The inclusion of the library (`implementation(...)`) should be located under sourceSets > commonMain > dependencies if you are trying to utilize this in multiplatform code. It's difficult to provide any more guidance without more information about how you have your project configured.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the window with your code tap - sync now. Sure you already added dependencies in build.gradle.kts